# Some web sites not shown in the "likes" of my Facebook app user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the following url to access the likes of the users of my Facebook Applications :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/?access_token=here_the_token
```

I get back the likes of my users, but I noted that I don't get the likes for some websites.

For example, I don't get back any like for sites like jaimeuh.fr (example : http://jaimeuh.fr/108, this is a french site, a bit spammy), through the API at least. Indeed, the like does appear in my personal stream on facebook.com.

My hypothesis is that some kind of spam prevention mechanism is at work, but I am not sure, and I obviously did not find anything about this in the Facebook API doc. Does somebody has an explanation for this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `<meta property="og:type" content="article" />` after test your web site with  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug the url linter :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that for a page to go through the API, it needs to give no error or warnings in the facebook debugger found at : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

The page I linked has some errors preventing it to be output through the API
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjaimeuh.fr%2F108

I had a similar problem for a page on a site that I am currently developping, and once all errors in the debugger were fixed, the links began to appear in the API.